# Validating Input goes into infinite loop

Tags: c, validation, goto

I am trying to validate the input if it is something else other than 1 to 3 it will prompt invalid input and also try to get a new input until it is valid.

This piece of code is working well when I'm trying to enter any number out of 1 to 3 but once I input alphabet the code goes into infinite loop.

```
    int searchBy;

searchInput:
    printf("1 - Search by id\n");
    printf("2 - Search by name\n");
    printf("3 - Search by marks\n>> ");
    printf("Please choose the searching method\n>> ");
    scanf("%d", &searchBy);
    if(searchBy >= 1 && searchBy <= 3){
        printf("Success");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nInvalid input please try again...\n\n");
        goto searchInput;
    }
```

I tried using while loop but it still goes into infinite loop when I am trying to input alpahbets. It seems like the program doesn't freeze at `scanf` but keep looping

```
while(searchBy >= 1 && searchBy <= 3 != 1){
        printf("\nInvalid input please try again...\n\n");
        printf("1 - Search by id\n");
        printf("2 - Search by name\n");
        printf("3 - Search by marks\n>> ");
        printf("Please choose the searching method\n>> ");
        scanf("%d", &searchBy);
    }
```

Comment: don't use `goto` for these kind of usecases, use loop instead also check the return value of `scanf` before proceeding.

Comment: Just stop there. Do not use `goto` like that. In fact, do not use `goto` at all until you are alot more expert in C. There are very rare cases where `goto` makes sense. Instead use proper loops and functions.

Comment: Edited the question, I tried using while loop but it still goes into infinite loop

Comment: Hint: `scanf` has a return value that means something.

Comment: I tried writing ```while(scanf("%d", &searchBy) == 0)``` but still runs into infinite loop, it doesn't freeze at ```scanf``` but just keep looping

Comment: You need to clear the input buffer after `scanf` fails. Alternatively, you can use `fgets` to read a line of input, and then use `sscanf` to extract the number.

Comment: The reason you want to read a *line-at-a-time* with `fgets()` and then parse with `sscanf` instead of reading with `scanf` is what remains in `stdin` after a *matching* failure occurs, for those *conversion-specifiers* that do not ignore leading whitespace, and to handle any extraneous characters in input. In either case you cannot use any function (and especially user-input functions) correctly unless you ***check the return***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to consume the character not accepted by `scanf`.....
One solution is to use `getchar()` after the 'scanf'.

```
scanf("%d", &searchBy);
getchar();//consume the character not accepted by scanf
if(searchBy >= 1 && searchBy <= 3){
    printf("Success");
}
else{
    printf("\nInvalid input please try again...\n\n");
    goto searchInput;
}
```

Comment: OP has "once I input alphabet the code goes into infinite loop.".  Not checking the return value of `scanf()` is crucial before using `searchBy`.  `getchar();` gets the next character, be it a newline of some other character.  This answer fixes  OP's problem by chance.

Answer (score 1):

In any case where you need specific input, you want to *loop continually* until the user provides the input you require. (force the user to input what you need), handle any invalid input, and repeat until you get what you need or the user generates a manual `EOF` canceling the input.

Trying to read with `scanf` is full of pitfalls for new C programmers due to what is left in `stdin` in the event of an input error. It is far better to declare an adequately sized buffer to handle all user input (including a cat accidentally stepping on the keyboard), using a *line-oriented* input function such as `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` and then parse the information your need from the buffer filled.

In this case, since you just care about the first-character of the input, there is no conversion required at all, simply `switch()` on the first character and take the appropriate action.

You could do something similar to:

```
#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...

    char buf[MAXC]; /* buffer to hold entire line of input */

    while (1) { /* loop continually until user chooses quit (or generates EOF) */
        /* display menu */
        fputs ( "\n1 - Search by id\n"
                "2 - Search by name\n"
                "3 - Search by marks\n"
                "q - quit\n\n"
                "choose search method: ", stdout);
        /* read entire line -- validate */
        if (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }

        switch (*buf) { /* switch on 1st char in buf */
            case '1':       /* do search by id here */
                break;
            case '2':       /* do search by name */
                break;
            case '3':       /* do search by marks */
                break;
            case 'q':
                goto done;  /* goto only used to break nested statements */
                break;
            default:    /* always handle the default: case */
                fputs ("error: invalid choice.\n", stderr);
                break;
        }
    }
    done:;  /* goto label */
```

(**note:** you can even use your `goto`, just not as you initially attempted. Also note you only need a single call to an output function to display your menu. The preprocessor will concatenate all adjacent double-quoted strings.)

Look things over, try it out, and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

! is used to negate the condition

```
 int x;
 printf("1 - Search by id\n");
 printf("2 - Search by name\n");
 printf("3 - Search by marks\n>> ");
 printf("Please choose the searching method\n>> ");
 x=scanf("%d", &searchBy);
while( !(searchBy >= 1 && searchBy <= 3) || (x!=1) ){
    printf("\nInvalid input please try again...\n\n");
    printf("1 - Search by id\n");
    printf("2 - Search by name\n");
    printf("3 - Search by marks\n>> ");
    printf("Please choose the searching method\n>> ");
    x=scanf("%d", &searchBy);
}
```

Comment: It still goes into infinite loop if you try to input alphabet